# Mongo function updatemany() is not working when Bson filters are passed

Tags: java, mongodb, bson

Below is the data present in Mongo DB

```
{"name":"john","id":"123","location":"Pune"}
{"name":"steve","id":"456","location":"Noida"}
```

I want to upsert the "id" to "789" and "name" to "alex" where "name":"john" and "location":"Pune" and as per upsert funtionality, if the query condition is not present, then it needs to create a new entry.

I am using the below logic to do this using Bson filter, but i am getting the below exception

```
Bson filter=null;
Bson update=null;

filter=combine(eq("name":"john"),eq("location":"Pune"));
update=combine(eq("id":"123"),eq("name":"alex"));
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();
options.upsert(true);
dbCollection.updateMany(filter, update,options);
```

I am expecting below change in my Mongo DB data :

```
{"name":"alex","id":"789","location":"Pune"}
```

**But I'm getting below Exception :**

```
Exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name portalID
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name portalID
at org.bson.AbstractBsonWriter.writeName(AbstractBsonWriter.java:532)
```

Can some one suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Bson filter = null;
Bson update = null;

filter = and(eq("name", "john"), eq("location", "Pune"));
update = combine(set("id", "789"), set("name", "alex"));
UpdateOptions options = new UpdateOptions();
options.upsert(true);
dbCollection.updateMany(filter, update, options);
```

Comment: @PavanKumar If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it.